# How to clone a synchronized Collection?

Tags: java, collections, synchronized

Imagine a **synchronized** `Collection`:

```
Set s = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet())
```

What's the best approach to clone this Collection?

It's prefered that the cloning doesn't need any synchronization on the original Collection but required that iterating over the cloned Collection does not need any synchronization on the original Collection.

Comment: What are the conditions of the copy?  Can the original set change while being copied?  What are you trying to accomplish by the clone?  (might be able to suggest more efficient way to achieve your goals, but need the answer to these questions to make sure it is correct for you)

Comment: @Berin Loritsch: Yes, the original set can change during copy. I am trying to get an Iterator from a Set which should be independent from the original Collection in sense of data and synchronization.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a copy-constructor inside a synchronized block:

```
synchronized (s) {
    Set newSet = new HashSet(s); //preferably use generics
}
```

If you need the copy to be synchronized as well, then use `Collections.synchronizedSet(..)` again.

As per Peter's comment - you'll need to do this in a synchronized block on the original set. The documentation of [`synchronizedSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedSet%28java.util.Set%29) is explicit about this:

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned set when iterating over it

Comment: Unfortunately this uses the Iterator under the bonnet, so you have to synchronize(s) to do this safely.

Comment: @Peter yes, obviously, there is hardly ever a way to access a collection without using iterators

Comment: the bad side of the story is that you must know how the method is implemented.

Answer (score 3):

When using synchronized sets, do understand that you will incur synchronization overhead accessing every element in the set.  The `Collections.synchronizedSet()` merely wraps your set with a shell that forces every method to be synchronized.  Probably not what you really intended.  A [`ConcurrentSkipListSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html) will give you better performance in a multithreaded environment where multiple threads will be writing to the set.

The `ConcurrentSkipListSet` will allow you to perform the following:

```
Set newSet = s.clone();//preferably use generics
```

It's not uncommon to use a clone of a set for snapshot processing.  If that's what you are after, you might add a little code to handle the case where the item is already processed.  The overhead involved with the occasional object included in more than one copy set is usually less than the consistent overhead of using `Collections.concurrentSet()`.

**EDIT:** I just noticed that ConcurrentSkipListSet is Cloneable and provides a threadsafe `clone()` method.  I changed my answer because I really believe this is the best option--instead of losing scalability and performance to `Collections.concurrentSet()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid synchronizing the set by doing the following which avoids exposing an Iterator on the original set.

```
Set newSet = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(s.toArray()));
```

EDIT From Collections.SynchronizedCollection

```
public Object[] toArray() {
    synchronized(mutex) {return c.toArray();}
}
```

As you can see, the lock is held for the entire time the operation is performed. As such a safe copy of the data is taken. It doesn't matter if an Iterator is used internally. The array returned can be used in a thread safe manner as only the local thread has a reference to it.

NOTE: If you want to avoid these issues I suggest you use a Set from the concurrency library added in Java 5.0 in 2004. I also suggest you use generics as this can make your collections more type safe.

Comment: True, but it iterates over a copy. this is thread safe. toArray() is thread safe because it is atomic.

Comment: I don't see anywhere that guarantees that `toArray()` is atomic--at least in the sense that matters in this case.  The only guarantee that I see is that the call to `toArray()` creates a new copy of an array--even if the collection is backed by an array.  I wouldn't want to stake my code on that assumption.  It takes time to copy arrays, particularly if the source is backed by nodes (as is the case with all sets and LinkedLists).  An iterator will be required in this case.

Comment: @Berin, Knowing how Collections.synchronizedSet() works, you can say any single operation is thread safe.  iterator() is thread safe but the Iterator it returns is not as it refers to the original collection and by the time you use it the lock has been released. toArray() is thread safe and it return a copy of the elements which only the thread holds so it too is thread safe.

Comment: Assuming it is a synchronizedSet(), your statement is correct.  However, I still maintain that the synchronizedSet will force you to lose some concurrency you may have been hoping to gain by running multiple threads.  Using a collection that is designed for concurrency will provide much finer grained control--but then your assumptions about the toArray will no longer apply.  It's important that people know what makes the call atomic as opposed to assuming it is all the time.

Comment: @Berin, The OP stated that he is using synchronizedSet(). I don't see how a collection could be designed for concurrency but its not safe to assume toArray() at the very least thread safe, if not atomic. (Only the former is actually required) Can you give an example of how this is possible?

Comment: Check out the source code for java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.java.html  It does not extend and make safe toArray().  I'd argue it was designed for concurrency--but the internal implementation will be as described here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toArray()

Comment: @Berin, you are correct that it uses the base toArray which uses Iterator, but Iterator is thread safe for this collection so the base implementation is fine AFAIK.

Comment: @Peter Lewray - that's an interesting discussion. As far as I see, the `iterator()` method for `PersistentCollection` is not thread-safe. Furthermore, the `toArray()` method uses the `iterator()` method of the wrapped collection. So if any thread has called `iterator()` on the synchronized collection, the `toArray()` will fail.

Comment: IMHO, if a collection is designed to be thread safe, but an individual implemented method can fail, that is a bug or a failure to meet the contract of the interface. It would be safer for toArray() to throw UnsupportedOperationException or say the collection is not actually thread safe.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey look at the code of the `iterator()` method. The comment says that the user must synchronize :) I agree this is strange, but it is at least documented.

Comment: @Bozho, It is strange given the concurrency collections don't provide way to lock the collection so doing this would be pointless.